# Click delay phantomjs node-horseman

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I've read around that a 300ms delay is inserted between clicks in order to detect double clicks.(on mobile devices) However I want to eliminate this delay, or at least shrink it to about 5ms.

The reason I need this, is because I currently loop through a set of elements and add click events to them, they are then clicked and expanded which reveals the data ready to be scraped. The website i am scraping is a mobile version of the desktop site.

I tried to include a library called FastClick, but couldn't get the working unfortunately and currently lost for ideas on how to eliminate the delay. Although it could be my code, any suggestions on how to speed it up?

```
var SELECTOR = 'li h2';
.evaluate(function (selector) {
        $(function() {
            FastClick.attach(document.body);
        });
        var els = $(selector);
        $.each(els, function (idx, el) {
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
    }, SELECTOR)
```

Comment: that delay is mainly on mobile devices, and if you call click(), it shouldn't be waiting at all...

Comment: Mobile sites, yes, i'm scraping the mobile version of the site, sorry i'll update my question.

Comment: right, but phantom.js is not a mobile browser, and last i used it, doesn't emulate touchscreen interaction.

Comment: Hmm true, i'd added my code which i need to optimize.